# JQuery Selector depending on a div that get's an added class when I swipe an img

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add create a selector depending on a div that get's an added class when I swipe an img. this is the look of the div before

```
<div id="ystq_container">
    <div class="ystq_buddy" >
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the div when the img is added:

```
<div id="ystq_container">
    <div class="ystq_buddy ystq_swipe-right" >
    </div>
</div>
```

now I'm trying to use the above question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div"). **(((((class on change))))** (function(){
        if($( ".ystq_buddy" ).hasClass( "ystq_swipe-right" )){
                    $(document.forms['f1']).submit();
                }

        });
</script>
```

what do we use to make something similar to on change as the input ! is there's any way to do so for a change on a div? or use on mouse event when I swipe the img?

Comment: can't use .on("change") as it's not an input!

Comment: ah I see, misunderstood your question :) removed comment :)

Comment: to add to @lonut's comment - you can use `.hasClass('className')` to test this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DOMSubtreeModified` for `div` and check your class is present or not.

```
$('.ystq_buddy').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
   if($( ".ystq_buddy" ).hasClass( "ystq_swipe-right" )){
         $(document.forms['f1']).submit();
    }
});
```